# Equivalent of NonZeroU8 but instead of 0, use u8::MAX?

Tags: rust

I want to be able to use `Option<NonZeroU8>` for its compact repr, but still be able to use 0.

Is there a way to use `u8::MAX` as the non-representable value instead of 0?

Comment: @kmdreko I was afraid so. It would be an awesome abstraction. The alternative is to do it explicitly in code, e.g. `if x == u8::MAX ...` which sounds like the best approach.

Comment: You could [add one](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d0e7220141998f6f2fcf6c4853dbbb2c) to move 0-254 to 1-255 and back but it's not really nice.

Answer (score 5):

To truly get the niche optimization directly, you'd have to use the super unstable `rustc_` attributes.

```
#![feature(rustc_attrs)]

#[rustc_layout_scalar_valid_range_start(0)]
#[rustc_layout_scalar_valid_range_end(254)]
struct NonMaxU8(u8);

fn main() {
    dbg!(std::mem::size_of::<Option<NonMaxU8>>());
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:8] std::mem::size_of::<Option<NonMaxU8>>() = 1
```

I say "super unstable" because these attributes will never be stabilized, at least not in their current form. Using them without `feature(rustc_attrs)` will emit the following message:

```
error[E0658]: the `#[rustc_layout_scalar_valid_range_start]` attribute is just used to enable niche optimizations in libcore and libstd and will never be stable
 --> src/main.rs:3:1
  |
3 | #[rustc_layout_scalar_valid_range_start(0)]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: add `#![feature(rustc_attrs)]` to the crate attributes to enable

error[E0658]: the `#[rustc_layout_scalar_valid_range_end]` attribute is just used to enable niche optimizations in libcore and libstd and will never be stable
 --> src/main.rs:4:1
  |
4 | #[rustc_layout_scalar_valid_range_end(254)]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: add `#![feature(rustc_attrs)]` to the crate attributes to enable
```

There have been asks for compiler support for ranged integers, like the discussion [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/671), but I don't think anything has been formally proposed as of yet.

Comment: We have [RFC #3334](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3334), but it is not accepted (yet?).

Answer (score 3):

There is the [nonmax](https://crates.io/crates/nonmax) crate that provides this. See [`NonMaxU8`](https://docs.rs/nonmax/0.5.3/nonmax/struct.NonMaxU8.html) specifically. This works because it uses `NonZeroU8` internally and does the appropriate conversion upon creation and the `.get()` method.

---

If you wanted a different variant, not just zero or max, you can easily make your own. The nonmax crate uses an XOR strategy to zero-out the non-representable value or use a modular arithmetic method like is suggested in the comments:

```
pub struct NonTenU8(NonZeroU8);

impl NonTenU8 {
    const UNREPRESENTABLE: u8 = 10;

    /// Creates a u8 value that cannot be ten.
    pub fn new(value: u8) -> Option<Self> {
        NonZeroU8::new(value ^ Self::UNREPRESENTABLE).map(Self)
        // NonZeroU8::new(value.wrapping_sub(Self::UNREPRESENTABLE)).map(Self)
    }

    pub fn get(&self) -> u8 {
        self.0.get() ^ Self::UNREPRESENTABLE
        // self.0.get().wrapping_add(Self::UNREPRESENTABLE)
    }
}
```